# How to trim array elements inside an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
const allData = 
[
  ['Alex   ','foo@email','   ',],
  ['  ','goo@gmail, '232-333-2222'],
]
```

I want to trim all values within the array so that for example `'Alex   '` becomes `'Alex'`.

I have tried these solutions:

```js
for (let data of allData.entries()) {
    for (let content of data) {
        content.trim();
    }
}
```

```js
allData.forEach((data) => {
    data.forEach((content) => {
        content.trim();
    });
});
```

```js
allData.map((data, index) => {
    return data.map((content) => content.trim());
});
```

I have tried `content = content.trim();` for all of them as well.

But even though it does trim the value it won't save the modified value in the array.

What am I missing? I want `allData` to contain the trimmed values.

Comment: `content.trim();` by itself is just an expression with no change because its not being assigned to anything.

Comment: Your code does the trimming but does not store the trimmed value back to the array.

Comment: `let` creates a scope bound instance. So assigning on that is futile for the other scope

Comment: `trim` doesn't modify the original string as they are immutable. You need to replace the array's index by changing the inner forEach to: `data.forEach((content, i) => data[i] = content.trim() )`

Comment: This is what I wanted. Thank you for the other answers as well :)

Comment: And `content = content.trim()` just reassigns the local parameter `content` with the trimmed string. It will not update the original array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no issues with your code (**the third version**). The only misunderstanding is that `.map()` does not modify the original array, but return a new one. Look:

```js
// This is basically your code.
const allData = 
[
  ['Alex   ','foo@email','   ',],
  ['  ','goo@gmail', '232-333-2222'],
];

 const trimmedAllData = allData.map((data, index) => {
    return data.map((content) => content.trim());
 });
 
 console.log(trimmedAllData);
```

Your **second try** can be easily fixed to modify the original `allData` values:

```js
const allData = 
[
  ['Alex   ','foo@email','   '],
  ['  ','goo@gmail', '232-333-2222'],
];

allData.forEach((data, i) => {
    data.forEach((content, j) => {
        allData[i][j] = content.trim(); // You have to write the trimmed value back!
    });
});
 
console.log(allData);
```

The **first version** is not a good enough approach.

Comment: This has nothing to with `map` not modifying the original array. Even `forEach` isn't working for OP

Comment: @adiga: I think it does. The OP has a basic misconception there as you can clearly see looking at his/her first and second solution. For the third one I think it is basically the same problem. So while this provides a solution I am not sure that it entirely removes the misconception the OP has.

Comment: @KrisztiánBalla the answer doesn't explain why `content.trim()` doesn't work in `forEach` or why `content = content.trim()` doesn't work.

Comment: @adiga I thought that is just what I've said. :-)

Comment: Thanks everyone. I have extended my answer a bit in order to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two nested [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and save the result in a new variable `res`:

```js
const allData = 
[
  ['Alex   ','foo@email','   ',],
  ['  ','goo@gmail', '232-333-2222'],
];

const res = allData.map( arr => arr.map(e => e.trim()) );

console.log(res);
```

If you want to use the for loops, you need to directly change the elements:

```js
const allData = 
[
  ['Alex   ','foo@email','   ',],
  ['  ','goo@gmail', '232-333-2222'],
];

allData.forEach((data,i) => {
  data.forEach((content,j) => {
    allData[i][j] = content.trim();
  });
});

console.log(allData);
```